Are there any practical uses for the copy() method of the frozenset objects?
In Python the frozenset type is the only built-in immutable type that has a copy() method. And it looks like this method always returns self:
>>> f1 = frozenset({1,2,3})
>>> f2 = f1.copy()
>>> f1 is f2
True

I don't see how this method could be useful, since technically it doesn't create a copy (a new object) at all. All other built-in immutable types don't have copy() method. Are there any practical use cases where it makes sense to use this method of frozenset objects?

The other immutable types aren't immutable versions of mutable built-in types (tuple and list may be closest, but they have different semantics). Not implementing the copy method would further restrict the number of places you can sub a frozenset in for a vanilla set, with no particular reason (it doesn't mutate anything, why prevent it?)

In other words: so set and frozenset present the same interface and you don’t need a special case for it.

@deceze keeping the interface stable shouldn't be a reason for unexpected behaviour?

@roganjosh What’s unexpected exactly?

I can't test at the moment but if I take it on face value, why should is be true here, even with a shallow copy?

@roganjosh Not sure, but does copy specify that it must return an object with a new id? Or does it just specify that it’ll return an object which can be safely modified independently of the original one? What is unexpected depends on your expectations and what they’re grounded in.

@deceze perhaps it's other languages that are muddling my thinking but I would expect a new heap allocation on the shallow copy of a flat collection. Perhaps that means I need to check my understanding more generally

@roganjosh The only time you should expect f1 is f2 to be true is following either f1 = f2 or f2 = f1. I don't think of a copy as a new blob of memory; that's just an implementation detail to ensure a more fundamental semantics, namely "if x is a copy of y and x is modified, then y is not modified". This statement remains true even if x isn't modifiable in the first place.

I’ll grant that you can very well ask why you’d want to create a copy if the copy isn’t modifiable in the first place. So, you can preserve the interface in that case, but it’d still break in other cases further down the line. But, well, perhaps it covers the odd case here and there, and it’s not any burden to provide this method, so why not?

@chepner I think we're agreeing here? .copy() is not 'f1 = f2` and yet the identity check is true here. Hence why I find this behaviour unexpected

@roganjosh In my opinion this result is expected for any object of an immutable type. For example, if x = 3, y = copy.copy(x) then x is y returns True. What was unexpected for me is that frozenset objects have a copy method. But as people say above, this has a reasonable explanation.

In that case, mission accomplished since it was your question to begin with :)

@roganjosh ”.copy() is not f1 = f2 and yet the identity check is true here” — The only guarantee is that the id must be the same when you do f1 = f2. That does not imply that the id must be different when making a copy. There’s simply no guarantee about ids in any form for that case.

@roganjosh No, you expect them to be different and are surprised to see they are the same. I only observe that f2 wasn't literaly set with f2 = f1, so I have no expectation about whether f1 is f2 should be true. Not assuming a statement is true is not the same as assuming it will be false.

@chepner that's a fair distinction indeed :)
